# Rxjava approach the get last Observable from each thread

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm thinking how to use RXJava for the scenario described bellow.

A `List<Object>`,each object will be sent to k8s and checked the status till the respone return true,so my polling active is that：

```
  private Observable<Boolean> startPolling(String content) {
    log.info("start polling "+ content);
    return Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .take(3)
      .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
      .flatMap(aLong -> Observable.just(new CheckSvcStatus().check(content)))
      .takeUntil(checkResult -> checkResult)
      .timeout(3000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Observable.just(false))
      ;
  }
```

Function of sent action:

```
Observable<Compo> sentYamlAndGet() {
  log.info("sent yaml");
  sentYaml()
  return Observable.just(content);
}
```

I try to use the `foreach` to get each object status which like this:

```
  public void rxInstall() throws JsonProcessingException {
    List<Boolean>observables = Lists.newArrayList();
    Observable.from(list)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
      .concatMap(s -> sendYamlAndGet())
      .timeout(3000l, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .subscribe()
    ;

    Observable.from(list).forEach(s -> {
      observables.add(Observable.just(s)
        .flatMap(this::startPolling)
        .toBlocking()
        .last()
      )
      ;
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(observables));
  }
```

Objects of outputs list is :`{"o1","o2","o3","o4","o5"}`
the last status of objest which I want is : `[false,true,false,false,true]`.

All above style is not much 'ReactX',check object status action do not affect to each other.

How to throw `foreach`? I trid `toIterable()`,`toList()` but failed.

```
  Observable.from(list)
  .concatMap(s -> sentYamlAndGet())
  .concatMap(this::startPolling)
  ....
  ;
```

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

> pps: currentlly I'm using rxjava1 `<version>1.2.0</version>` but can change to 2(´▽`)ﾉ

Comment: Why dont you try using circuit breaker pattern, this looks a perfect usecase

Comment: @Niraj Chauhan I want to controll it exactly,did polling action not use circuit breaker pattern like timeout operator? I'm new one at this(°Д°)

Comment: With the help of circuit breaker, you would achieve polling in your controlled way, but the only benefit you will get is that if the endpoint is down then why you want to keep polling for regular interval? Instead circuit breaker will retry automatically after some time